# tap gesture on uiimage in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In each cell of my `UICollectionView`, I have multiple object to interact with.
So instead of use `didSelect` delegate method, I really wanted to add a tap gesture on each object of the cell.

To make it simple, I removed all the other objects in the example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlacesCollectionViewCell

  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gotToSelectedPlace:")
  tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

  cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
  cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  cell.imageView.file = places[indexPath.row].picture
  cell.imageView.loadInBackground()

  return cell

}
```

In viewDidLoad, I use a nib :

```
collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PlacesCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

UICollectionView Settings:

- Delays Content Touches: True
- Cancellable Content Touches: True

With this example, I can't handle the tap gesture. Nothing happen.
Did I miss something??

Thanks

Comment: Your running into an issue. The cells already have a tap gesture with one tap. That's simply selecting it. Can you not handle your interactions in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and then didDeselect?

Comment: What type of object is the imageView?  A standard UIImageView doesn't have a `file` property or `loadInBackground()` method.  This is likely the issue

Comment: I forget to mention, this one is a PFFile, subclass of UIImageView...

Comment: @soulshined I did not use the didSelect delegate method so no issue in my point of view. don't you think ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one

```
 var doubletapgesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "processDoubleTap:")
        doubletapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(doubletapgesture)
```

now handle gesture

```
func processDoubleTap (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            var point:CGPoint = sender.locationInView(collectionView)
            var indelPath:NSIndexPath =collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
            if indexPath
            {
                println("image taped")
            }
            else
            {
               //Do Some Other Stuff Here That Isnt Related;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works as this, but I have to check every point location of my objects... don't understand why my code is not working, much easier.

Comment: in your case, you are adding gesture for each cell its too much memory consuming.

Comment: if you have more than one gesture in UIViewController that it might be conflict with each other.