# CollectionView inside of Container View not performing tapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uicontainerview

So the setup I have is a Container View with a Collection View inside of that it. Inside of the Collection view is where I have "messageImageView ". However, when I try and tap messageImageView, it doesn't perform the function. Below is the code i'm using

```
let messageImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 24
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomTap)))
    return imageView

}()
    func handleZoomTap(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("thisisatest")
}
```

Comment: Use `UIButton` instead of `UIImageView`.

Comment: please, look this theme
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459715/tap-gesture-on-uiimage-in-collectionview

Comment: @Daivest No luck. I tried applying the answer and it still isn't working

Comment: Hi, is this `messageImageView` inside an `UICollectionViewCell`? Can you add the code for how you're inserting it into UICollectionView?

Comment: hi @KrishnaCA yes the messageImageView is inside of a UICollectionViewCell, and I just registered it into my UICollectionView